# Htaccess silent redirect subpage to GET variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to silently redirect all subpages of a particular page:

```
http://example.com/page/profile/john-smith
http://example.com/page/profile/ted-smith/
```

Redirect to the following internally (without the user seeing the redirect)

```
http://example.com/page/profile?id=john-smith
http://example.com/page/profile?id=ted-smith
```

How would I achieve this with a simple Htaccess rewrite rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following rule in root/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^page/profile/((?!index).+)/?$ /page/profile/?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

This will internally redirect  `/page/profile/foo` to  `/page/profile/?id=foo` .